# Error checkPermission a simple Bluetooth application with Android Studio

Tags: android, permissions

I'm trying a simple Bluetooth application with Android Studio. I am getting a total of 5 errors in this code. In the errors it says I have problems with permissions. I tried a lot but I couldn't solve the errors. No matter how many different methods I tried, it didn't work. I would be glad if you help me in this regard.

Error : Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with `checkPermission`) or explicitly handle a potential `SecurityException`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button GetDevBtn, ConnectBtn, SendBtn;
    EditText InputTxt;
    TextView ResultTxt;

    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothDevice bluetoothDevice;
    BluetoothSocket bluetoothSocket;
    IntentFilter intentFilter;

    RxThread rxThread;
    String RxData = "";

    InputStream inputStream;
    OutputStream outputStream;

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BLUETOOTH = 2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        GetDevBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        ConnectBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        SendBtn = findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        InputTxt = findViewById(R.id.txt1);
        ResultTxt = findViewById(R.id.txt2);

        bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
        intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);

        rxThread = new RxThread();

        registerReceiver(Btreceiver, intentFilter);
        ConnectBtn.setEnabled(false);


        GetDevBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                **Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                for (BluetoothDevice dev : devices) {
                    if (dev.getName().equals("PARTHA BT0")) {
                        bluetoothDevice = dev;
                        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();**
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        ConnectBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {


                    **bluetoothSocket = bluetoothDevice.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB"));
                    bluetoothSocket.connect();**
                    inputStream = bluetoothSocket.getInputStream();
                    outputStream = bluetoothSocket.getOutputStream();
                    rxThread.start();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"CONNECTED",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {}

            }
        });


        SendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    outputStream.write((InputTxt.getText() + "\r\n").getBytes());
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        });


    }

    class RxThread extends Thread {
        public boolean isRunning;
        byte[] rx;
        RxThread() {
            isRunning = true;
            rx = new byte[10];
        }
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (isRunning) {
                try {
                    if(inputStream.available()>2) {
                        inputStream.read(rx);
                        RxData = new String(rx);
                    }
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            if(!RxData.equals("")) {
                                ResultTxt.setText(RxData);
                                RxData = "";
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }


    BroadcastReceiver Btreceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            switch (intent.getAction()) {
                case BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED:
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            ConnectBtn.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED:
                    rxThread.isRunning = false;
                    break;
            }
        }
    };


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check for Permission:

Before performing the operation that requires the permission, you should check whether the required permission has been granted.
Request Permission:

If the permission is not granted, request it from the user. You'll need to provide a rationale explaining why the permission is needed.
Handle SecurityException:

Wrap the operation that requires the permission in a try-catch block to catch and handle any potential SecurityException that may be thrown.

Comment: I tried but couldn't do it.